# Is foldRight equivalent to foldLeft given a noncommutative associative operation?

Tags: scala, fold, equivalent

In a online course it was stated that `foldLeft` and `foldRight` are equivalent for operators that are **associative and commutative**.

One of the students is adamant that such operators only need to be associative. So this property should be true for operations like function composition and matrix multiplication.

As far as I can tell an associative operation that isn't commutative will not produce equivalent results for `foldLeft` and `foldRight` unless `z` is neutral and the operation is accumulated in such a way that the order of the operands remains untouched. IMO the operation has to be commutative in the general case.

```
list.foldLeft(z)(operation) == list.foldRight(z)(operation)
```

So, for `foldLeft` and `foldRight` to be equivalent should `operation` be simultaneously associative and commutative or is it enough for `operation` to be associative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function must be both commutative and associative.

If our function is `f`, and our elements are `x1` to `x4`, then:

foldLeft is `f(f(f(x1, x2), x3), x4)`

foldRight is `f(x1, f(x2, f(x3, x4)))`

Let's use the average function, which is commutative but not associative (`(a + b) / 2 == (b + a) / 2`):

```
scala> def avg(a: Double, b: Double): Double = (a + b) / 2
avg: (a: Double, b: Double)Double

scala> (0 until 10).map(_.toDouble).foldLeft(0d)(avg)
res4: Double = 8.001953125

scala> (0 until 10).map(_.toDouble).foldRight(0d)(avg)
res5: Double = 0.9892578125
```

EDIT: I missed the boat on only associative vs only commutative. See @jwvy's example of string concatenation for an associative but not commutative function.

Comment: Good catch.  Will refer to @jwvh's string concatenation.

Answer (score 8):

`String` concatenation ("abc" + "xyz") is associative but not commutative and `foldLeft`/`foldRight` will place the initial/zero element at opposite ends of the resulting string. If that zero element is not the empty string then the results are different.

Answer (score 4):

foldLeft is `(...(z op x1)... op xn)`
foldRight is `x1 op (x2 op (... xn op z)...)`
So the `op` needs to be commutative and associative for the two to be equivalent in the general case

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three relevant cases with separate answers:

1. In the general case where `op: (B, A) -> B` or `op: (A, B) -> B`, as in the signatures of `foldLeft` and `foldRight`, neither associativity nor commutativity are defined.
2. If `B >: A` and `z` is a two-sided **identity** of `op: (B, B) -> B` and `op` is **associative** then for all `L` of type `List[A]`, `L.foldLeft(z)(op)` returns the same result as `L.foldRight(z)(op)`.

   This is closely related to the fact that if `B >: A` and `op: (B, B) -> B` then, if `op` is associative, for all `L` of type `List[A]` `L.reduceLeft(op)` returns the same result as `L.reduceRight(op)`.
3. If `B >: A`, and `op: (B, B) -> B` is both **associative and commutative** then for all `L` of type `List[A]` and `z` of type `B`, `L.foldLeft(z)(op)` returns the same result as `L.foldRight(z)(op)`.